# Is there a configuration setting in NetSuite that restricts the include transaction workflow feature on the send email action?

Tags: workflow, netsuite

I have created a Vendor Bill approval workflow that notifies approvers when a Bill has been entered.  However, no matter what I try it won't include the transaction in the email (as a PDF, Inline Below, etc).

The feature does work for my Purchase Order Approval workflow, but not for my Vendor Bill approvals.

Does anyone know of a configuration setting within NetSuite that may be restricting this feature for Vendor Bills specifically?

Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate your question by providing the code sample used or links for screenshot of your configuration.

Comment: I have never seen this. As you mention I have done it on many other transaction types. You may want to try a simple workflow on Vendor bills that does nothing but send an email and include the pdf. If that fails, post a screenshot of the config here and maybe we can try to help. Otherwise you may want to send that to support as a possible bug

Comment: I'll give that a try.  I'm also going to reach out to NetSuite support, see if they see something I don't.  Thanks!